# More Statistical Way to Average N Predictions

Tags: predictive-models, random-forest, prediction, model-averaging, forecast-combination

I've run a RandomForestRegressor (Scikit Ensemble) over N loops, each time changing the random seed and therefore changing the train test split. This way I've N sets of predictions (M predictions for each loop). I've also captured the following data

R2_Score for Train Dataset over N Loops (1 value per loop)

R2_Score for Test Dataset over N Loops (1 value per loop)

Currently, I average out all the predictions for which R2_Score_Train > Median(R2_Score_Train) && R2_Score_Test > Median(R2_Score_Test)

I want to know a better way to make out the final predictions, using the R2_Score for both train and test dataset. One way I was thinking to is to give more weight to a loop for which R2_Score_Train ~ R2_Score_Test (i.e. the difference between them is the smallest) and lowering the weights for which this value is high.

I am using Python for this. Scikit-Learn. Wanted to know if there is any inbuilt function or any 3rd party library?

Answer (score 8):

Generally an average of a set of forecasts gives a better forecast than any individual forecast, so why not use all the forecasts, even the poor ones? The question - you also ask - is how to do this. The most simple way is to use [weighted mean](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139536/how-should-i-determine-an-average-from-a-set-of-averages/139567#139567), where you weight each forecast by the inverse error. This makes 'poor' forecasts have a low weight and the 'good' ones to have high weight. There are more sophisticated approaches, check the references for learning more.

---

Winkler and Makridakis (1983). [The Combination of Forecasts.](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Spyros_Makridakis/publication/261805839_The_Combination_of_Forecasts/links/54be3a1a0cf218da9391df50.pdf) *J. R. Statis. Soc. A. 146*(2), 150-157.

Makridakis and Winkler (1983). [Averages of Forecasts: Some Empirical Results.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.320.2933&rep=rep1&type=pdf) *Management Science, 29*(9) 987-996.

Clemen (1989). [Combining forecasts: A review and annotated bibliography.](https://faculty.fuqua.duke.edu/~clemen/bio/Published%20Papers/13.CombiningReview-Clemen-IJOF-89.pdf) *International Journal of Forecasting, 5,* 559-583.

Bates, J. M., & Granger, C. W. (1969). [The combination of forecasts.](ftp://rammftp.cira.colostate.edu/Knaff/Annular_pres/3008764.pdf) *Or,* 451-468.

Answer (score 0):

There are "more statistical" ways, but they're not better. It's known as a "forecast combination puzzle", when a simple average outperforms other more sophisticated weighting schemes. I don't think there's a definitive answer to why it happens but you can find a lot of papers on this subject, e.g. ["A Simple Explanation of the Forecast Combination Puzzle" Jeremy Smith,
Kenneth F. Wallis](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1468-0084.2008.00541.x/abstract)

My explanation is that your weighting schemes are based on the estimates themselves. You don't *know* the optimal weights, you must estimate them. This brings in the estimation error, which when combined with the individual forecast errors in aggregation increases the combined forecast error.